# Jboss EAP 7 symbolic link to log file in welcome-content does not work

Tags: jboss, wildfly, symlink, jboss-eap-7

I want an easy way to view / download the log files on test server (for external vendor who does not have access to the server via ssh).

What i've tried to do within the {jboss home}/welcome-content folder:

ln -s {jboss home}/standalone/log/server.log server.log

This creates symbolic link to the log file, but when i try to view the log file through chrome : http://{internal ip}:8080/server.log  it does not work.

If i do ln -P , to create a physical link it works, but when the log file rolls over (i.e. end of day) its still pointing to the old log file and not to the new server.log, which is not desirable.

I also do not want to go through the trouble of creating a new war file and deploying it just for displaying log files.

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont have a solution, but i have a workaround. Create the physical link every time the log file roles over, since we do nightly builds, after the server starts up, shell script runs the ln -P command. Still wonder why the symbolic link doesnt work in welcome-content

Comment: In EAP 7 you can check log files in management console, it will show ll log files from server log directory. have you tried with that approach ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try it, but i get the following error :
 "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [(\"subsystem\" => \"logging\")]
I am guessing this is due to us removing default configurations in standalone.xml that was conflicting with our log4j. For what its worth your suggestion may be a valid solution for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Though you said in a comment you removed the logging subsystem, there are a few ways to get download a log file via the HTTP management interface. They do require the logging subsystem to be present though and the log file must be in the `jboss.server.log.dir` and a known file handler.

With curl:

```
curl --digest -L -D - http://127.0.0.1:9990/management?useStreamAsResponse --header "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin:admin.1234 -d '{"operation":"read-attribute","address":[{"subsystem":"logging"},{"log-file":"server.log"}],"name":"stream"}' -o server.log
```

Or in a browser:
http://localhost:9990/management/subsystem/logging/log-file/server.log?operation=attribute&name=stream&useStreamAsResponse

As another comment mentions you can also use the management console itself.

Another option would be to use the management API to create your own function to download.

```java
try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9990)) {
    final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("subsystem", "logging", "log-file", "server.log");
    final ModelNode op = Operations.createReadResourceOperation(address);
    op.get("include-runtime").set(true);
    final OperationResponse response = client.executeOperation(OperationBuilder.create(op).build(), OperationMessageHandler.logging);
    final ModelNode outcome = response.getResponseNode();
    if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(outcome)) {
        final String uuid = Operations.readResult(outcome).get("stream").asString();
        final InputStream in = response.getInputStream(uuid).getStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

Again though all these options require the logging subsystem to be used.

Comment: Im reluctant to mark this as correct, as the original issue of symbolic link not working remains. But have my upvote for the helpful suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: Understandable. I mainly just "as-is" with the question since it was just a comment about not using the logging subsystem.